# How subtotal a dataframe and also grandtotal

Tags: r, dplyr, kableextra, gt

I'm looking for a way to summarize my dataframe into a summary table that will have the total sum of each observation and the entire sum in percentage and also the total count and total count in percentage and each having a subgroup of total and also Grand total of each observation.

here is my sample dataset below.

```
struct<- samples_stack <- dput(samples[1:50,])
structure(list(Merchant = c("Fat", "Fat", "United", "WAVE", "Fat", 
                            "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "WAVE", "WAVE", "WAVE", "WAVE", 
                            "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", 
                            "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "WAVE", "WAVE", "WAVE", "WAVE", "WAVE", 
                            "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", 
                            "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", "Fat", 
                            "Fat"), Network = c("G", "G", "G", "X9", "G", "G", "M", "M", 
                                                "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "G", "G", "G", "G", "A", "A", "A", 
                                                "A", "G", "G", "G", "G", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "G", "G", "G", 
                                                "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
                                                "G", "G", "G"), Type = c("Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Data", "Airtime", "Data", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Data", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Data", "Data", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Airtime", "Airtime", "Data", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Data", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Data", "Data", "Airtime", "Airtime", 
                                                                         "Data", "Data", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime", "Airtime"
                                                ), FaceValue = c(200, 200, 2000, 100, 100, 100, 100, 300, 500, 
                                                                 300, 240, 600, 400, 600, 100, 500, 130, 200, 500, 100, 100, 300, 
                                                                 150, 300, 300, 2000, 200, 240, 600, 400, 400, 500, 250, 100, 
                                                                 100, 500, 450, 50, 1300, 1400, 1400, 2000, 100, 130, 130, 100, 
                                                                 100, 200, 200, 600), Date = c("2022-12-03 23:37:23", "2022-12-03 22:45:52", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 06:58:19", "2022-12-03 14:06:28", "2022-12-03 22:19:13", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 22:15:39", "2022-12-03 20:02:12", "2022-12-03 20:01:07", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 19:14:25", "2022-12-03 14:47:35", "2022-12-03 23:12:40", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 23:09:18", "2022-12-03 22:57:57", "2022-12-03 22:51:16", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 21:23:38", "2022-12-03 21:19:43", "2022-12-03 21:03:38", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 20:57:44", "2022-12-03 22:51:07", "2022-12-03 22:26:50", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 21:57:09", "2022-12-03 21:53:54", "2022-12-03 20:20:21", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 20:13:07", "2022-12-03 20:10:30", "2022-12-03 19:50:21", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 01:28:35", "2022-12-03 01:17:59", "2022-12-03 00:35:08", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 00:31:56", "2022-12-03 00:11:25", "2022-12-03 18:36:51", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 17:56:25", "2022-12-03 17:10:15", "2022-12-03 16:49:27", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 16:45:03", "2022-12-03 16:43:26", "2022-12-03 16:37:55", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 16:36:11", "2022-12-03 16:14:40", "2022-12-03 16:03:10", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 16:02:56", "2022-12-03 15:32:37", "2022-12-03 15:30:45", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 15:14:05", "2022-12-03 15:13:24", "2022-12-03 15:09:10", 
                                                                                               "2022-12-03 12:20:58", "2022-12-03 11:54:15", "2022-12-03 11:36:53"
                                                                 ), Status = c("Processing", "Transaction Declined", "Successful", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Processing", "Transaction Declined", "Processing", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Processing", "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", 
                                                                               "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", 
                                                                               "Transaction Declined", "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", "Processing", 
                                                                               "Transaction Declined", "Processing", "Transaction Declined", 
                                                                               "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", "Processing", 
                                                                               "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", "Processing", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", 
                                                                               "Processing", "Processing", "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", 
                                                                               "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined", "Transaction Declined"
                                                                 ), Discount... = c("6.00", "6.00", "5.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", 
                                                                                    "3.70", "3.70", "3.70", "3.70", "3.20", "3.20", "3.20", "3.20", 
                                                                                    "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "3.50", "3.50", "3.50", "3.50", 
                                                                                    "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "3.50", "3.50", "3.50", "3.50", 
                                                                                    "3.50", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", 
                                                                                    "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", 
                                                                                    "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00"), Discount.NGN. = c("12.00", "12.00", 
                                                                                                                                       "100.00", "6.00", "6.00", "6.00", "3.70", "11.10", "18.50", "11.10", 
                                                                                                                                       "7.68", "19.20", "12.80", "19.20", "6.00", "30.00", "7.80", "12.00", 
                                                                                                                                       "17.50", "3.50", "3.50", "10.50", "9.00", "18.00", "18.00", "120.00", 
                                                                                                                                       "7.00", "8.40", "21.00", "14.00", "14.00", "30.00", "15.00", 
                                                                                                                                       "6.00", "6.00", "30.00", "27.00", "3.00", "78.00", "84.00", "84.00", 
                                                                                                                                       "120.00", "6.00", "7.80", "7.80", "6.00", "6.00", "12.00", "12.00", 
                                                                                                                                       "36.00"), Network.reformat = c("G", "G", "G-s", "X9", "G", "G", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "G", "G", "G", "G", "A", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "A", "A", "A", "G", "G", "G", "G", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "G", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "G", "G", "G", "G", "G")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want my table to look like the table below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grouped `summarize()` and `mutate()` to get initial values, then do additional summaries within `bind_rows()` to add subtotals and totals. Finally, use `forcats::fct_relevel()` inside `dplyr::arrange()` to put everything in order.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

samples_stack %>%
  group_by(Network, Merchant) %>%
  summarize(
    Count_Merchant = n(), 
    Sum_FaceValue = sum(FaceValue),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Pct_Merchant = Count_Merchant / sum(Count_Merchant),
    Pct_FaceValue = Sum_FaceValue / sum(Sum_FaceValue)
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(
    summarize(
      group_by(., Network),
      Merchant = "SUBTOTAL",
      across(Count_Merchant:Pct_FaceValue, sum)
    ),
    summarize(
      .,
      across(Network:Merchant, ~ "TOTAL"),
      across(Count_Merchant:Pct_FaceValue, sum)
    )
  ) %>%
  arrange(
    fct_relevel(Network, "TOTAL", after = Inf),
    fct_relevel(Merchant, "SUBTOTAL")
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   Network Merchant Count_Merchant Sum_FaceValue Pct_Merchant Pct_FaceValue
   <chr>   <chr>             <int>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 A       SUBTOTAL              9          2840         0.18       0.130  
 2 A       Fat                   4          1000         0.08       0.0457 
 3 A       WAVE                  5          1840         0.1        0.0841 
 4 G       SUBTOTAL             32         15890         0.64       0.727  
 5 G       Fat                  31         13890         0.62       0.635  
 6 G       United                1          2000         0.02       0.0914 
 7 M       SUBTOTAL              8          3040         0.16       0.139  
 8 M       Fat                   4          1200         0.08       0.0549 
 9 M       WAVE                  4          1840         0.08       0.0841 
10 X9      SUBTOTAL              1           100         0.02       0.00457
11 X9      WAVE                  1           100         0.02       0.00457
12 TOTAL   TOTAL                50         21870         1          1
```